# Does Google+ API allow you to get circle counts?

Tags: google-plus

I want to get the # of circles that have Huffington Post for example:
https://plus.google.com/101423092138897438495/posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can not access any circle information from Google+ through the API. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9) to surface it however.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll need to do some web scraping for now.

Comment: @QuyLe - Were you successful at scraping?  Looks complicated since circle counts is populated from javascript and the XHR requests look gnarly.

Comment: Yes, I was able to find a way to get circle counts. Basically, I wrote a script using curl to post my authentication credentials first and then scraped the HTML source. It's not too hard after that.